# New-ish to GoBoard, stud spacing question

Tags: shower, tile, framing

Recently, I spent a summer working for a professional tile installer. I had a great deal of DIY experience already mainly with Hardie, Regauard and Kerdie products. It seems a lot of pros however favor GoBoard, Hydro Ban Laticrete though it is more expensive, it is easier to work with, is already water proof (unlike hardie) and simply requires a urethane sealant over holes/seams. My concern is with the stud spacing on some installs. While we always followed the manufacturer recommendations, even in a shower we never bothered with smaller than 16" OC.

Now I'm doing my own shower in GoBoard and the 16" spacing has me concerned. It is a large walk-in with a lot of body jets, etc. All on 16" spacing except a few spots where it's less than that. I can push the GoBoard slightly in the middle of two studs with little effort a solid 1/4". This was the same on all the tub shower combos I did with GoBoard before and was told by the company it's fine, and per manufacturer spec which it was. If anyone broke it, means they were being overly rough/slamming into walls etc.

I recently read the instructions (again) and GoBoard clearly stresses 16" OC. I guess I just question this in a large shower with lots of space where someone might lean against a wall. But perhaps I am being overly worrisome? My wife definitely leans against walls, and is IMO kinda rough on showers in general.

Comment: Hardie board is available in a waterproof version for some time now.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Oh interesting... I see that now. I think it's just not as easy to find in the Lowes/Home Depots, or I haven't noticed. Thanks, i'll have to give that a try maybe on the next one.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider installing bands of blocking (2x6 or 2x8, "flatways") between studs at "likely body contact heights" (average hip and shoulder, or wife-specific hip and shoulder) which have the additional function of being places you can screw grab bars to (now, or later if not desired now) - alternatively, layer plywood or stiffer cementboard on top of the studs and behind the more flexible go-board, if the go-board is doing the waterproofing.

Never heard of the product before your post, but I can't imagine tile holding well with that much movement of the substrate.

A plywood or cementboard overlay will, of course, change the size of the finished shower slightly.